# Reder only specific key value based on another key value with Javascript in React component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In my React application I need to grep the `url` with `"type": "Three"`?

How to find and return only specific key value based on another key value with Javascript?

From the api I get an array of images:

```
   "images": [
        {
          "url": "https:example/c18336d6-61ee-4c7c-be6b-397352b6fd63",
          "type": "One"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://example/c18336d6-61ee-4c7c-be6b-397352b6fd63",
          "type": "Two"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://example/c18336d6-61ee-4c7c-be6b-397352b6fd63",
          "type": "Three"
        },
      ]
    },
```

Then in my React component I want to use this value:

```
    const MyComponent = () => {

      const items =
        nodes.map((item) => {
            return {
              myImage: // Here I need e.g. the url value of the images array with type = Three.
                       // Like https://example/c18336d6-61ee-4c7c-be6b-397352b6fd63
            };
          }) || [];

   return <Slides items={items} />

  export default MyComponent;
```